# MySQL not updating information_schema, unless I manually run ANALYZE TABLE `myTable`

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema, mysql-8.0

I have the need to get last id (primary key) of a table (InnoDB), and to do so I perform the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mySchema' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'myTable') - 1;
```

which returns the wrong AUTO_INCREMENT. The problem is the TABLES table of information_schema is not updated with the current value, unless I run the following query:

```
ANALYZE TABLE `myTable`;
```

Why doesn't MySQL update information_schema automatically, and how could I fix this behavior?
Running MySQL Server 8.0.13 X64.

Comment: I would guess that INNODB databases keep that somewhere else

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Q:** Why doesn't MySQL update information_schema automatically, and how could I fix this behavior?

**A:** InnoDB holds the auto_increment value in memory, and doesn't persist that to disk.

Behavior of metadata queries (e.g. `SHOW TABLE STATUS`) is influenced by setting of `innodb_stats_on_metadata` and `innodb_stats_persistent` variables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata

Forcing an ANALYZE everytime we query metadata can be a drain on performance.

Other than the settings of those variables, or forcing statistics to be collected by manually executing the `ANALYZE TABLE`, I don't think there's a "fix" for the issue.

(I think that mostly because I don't think it's a problem that needs to be fixed.)

---

To get the highest value of an auto_increment column in a table, the normative pattern is:

```
 SELECT MAX(`ai_col`) FROM `myschema`.`mytable`
```

---

What puzzles me is why we need to retrieve this particular piece of information. What are we going to use it for?

Certainly, we aren't going to use that in application code to determine a value that was assigned to a row we just inserted.  There's no guarantee that the highest value isn't from a row that was inserted by some other session. And we have `LAST_INSERT_ID()` mechanism to retrieve the value of a row our session just inserted.

If we go with the `ANALYZE TABLE` to refresh statistics, there's still a small some time between that and a subsequent `SELECT`... another session could slip in another `INSERT` so that the value we get from the gather stats could be "out of date" by the time we retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I thought MAX(`id`) could slow the query so found this other approach, but unfortunately doesn't work for InnoDB tables. My use case is the following: i have a table which contains spatial coordinates and on a new insertion, I have to check if the new location is within 10m radius. If so, discard the location. Do you think using this approach is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Having a suitable index available should make for reasonable performance of `SELECT MAX(mycol) FROM mytable`. The only thing wrong with the use case its a little vague. We need to check if the coordinates of our new (to be inserted) row is within 10mi of the coordinates on the row with the highest value of ai_col ? If we're going to have to query the table to get the coordinates, then we could just do it with something along the lines of `SELECT r.coordinate_col FROM mytable r JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t.id) AS max_id FROM mytable t ) s ON s.max_id = r.id`.

Comment: If we're needing to compute the "as the crow flies" Great Circle Distance, we could make the query a little more elaborate, push in the coordinates for our proposed row, do the GCD calculation, and return a distance...

Comment: I do it the following way: @params lng, lat @returns true->location already exists, false->location doesn't exist:   
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `location`) AND ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(?, ?), `lnglat`) <= 10);
By the way this is not the problem, only the fact the I couldn't retrieve updated values in information_schema. Thanks guys :)

Comment: I'd use EXPLAIN to see the query plan; I'd opt for a `JOIN` to an inline view over the `id  = (subquery)` pattern.  We just want to make sure MySQL is whittling the result down to a single single row *before* it launches into the distance calculations, we only need to do that on one row.   I'd tend to do something like:  `SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(?, ?), t.lnglat) <= 10 AS bool_ FROM location t JOIN ( SELECT MAX(r.id) AS max_id FROM location r ) s ON s.max_id = t.id`

Comment: I checked both queries using `EXPLAIN` and yours looks better because it uses indexes better. But wouldn't this query be even better since it uses 2 operations instead of 3? `SELECT ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(-122.084,37.4219983),lnglat) <= 10 FROM location WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM location);`

Comment: @YanKarin - The subquery is unnecessary if you use `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.  (Similar to my answer.)  Your query (and my variant) will return true/false (1/0) depending on whether it is within 10 units of distance.  (Be careful what your units are.)

Comment: This is the result of the two `EXPLAIN` as an image, since it's a mess as text:  
https://i.imgur.com/qezdKPB.jpg  
Based on the output, which one should I choose (and maybe why)?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY insert_datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

will get you all the data from, the "latest" inserted row.  No need to deal with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, no need to use subqueries, no `ANALYZE`, no `information_schema`, no extra fetch once you have the id, no etc, etc.

Yes, you do need an index on the column that you use to determine what is "latest".  Yes, `id` *could* be used, but it should not be.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are guaranteed to be unique, but *nothing* else.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is now 5 years old, but spencer7593's comments need to be addressed because this is still an issue.

"To get the highest value of an auto_increment column in a table, the normative pattern is:

SELECT MAX(`ai_col`) FROM `myschema`.`mytable`"

This is often used to get the last identity value inserted into a table.  It is such a common query that it **should** be updated either in information_schema or in a global variable, eg @last_identity_insert.  When doing multiple inserts into a table and related tables the last identity value is required for foreign keys.  That's just one example.

Similarly, information_schema.table_rows: needs to be current.  Selecting count(*) from a large table is a huge performance hit.  Selecting a current value from information_schema is not.

"Forcing an ANALYZE everytime we query metadata can be a drain on performance"

ANALYZE should not even be necessary.  When an insert into a table is done the db knows how many rows are affected. Should be a simple matter to update the table's row count.

This is an annoyance.  Other major RDBMS venders do not have this issue.